# A generating function associated with Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

I have an equation for Fibonacci numbers:

$f_n =f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$

So, using generating functions, I get:

$G(z)=zG(z)+z^2G(z)+z$

I don't understand where does the 'z' in the third term come from? Can anyone explain?

Thanks.

Comment: "You" get but "you" are not able to explain? Strange hum

Comment: Why don't you show the derivation that got you that expression? It's hard to guess where you got it from.

Comment: Maybe the final $+z$ shouldn't be there...

Comment: I saw this expression in a paper. What I get does not include $z$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the recurrence relation only makes sense for $n \ge 2$, you would need to start off any summation based on that recurrence relation at $n=2$:
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty f_n z^n = \sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{n-1} z^n + \sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{n-2} z^n.$$
Now, since you're starting the sum of the left hand side at $n=2$ instead of at $n=0$, this actually gives $G(z) - f_0 - f_1 z = G(z) - z$.  Likewise, after shifting indices on the right hand side, you get
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{n-1} z^n + \sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{n-2} z^n = z \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n z^n + z^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n z^n = z (G(z) - f_0) + z^2 G(z) = z G(z) + z^2 G(z).$$

Comment: Ok. So $G(z)-0-z=zG(z)+z^2G(z)$. And thus, $G(z)=z/{1-z-z^2}$. Understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The $z$ comes from the initial conditions, which for Fibonacci are $f_0 = 0$, $f_1 = 1$.
Note that the recursion is not valid for $n=0$ or $n=1$.

Comment: So, when I multiply by $\sum z^n$, I get, $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}f_nz_n=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}f_{n-1}z_n+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}f_{n-2}z_n$. Can you explain after this?

Comment: I would add, this means that the equation $$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty f_n z^n = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty f_{n - 1} z^n + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty f_{n - 2} z^n $$ doesn't make sense for the first two terms of the summation.

Comment: Indeed, $\sum_{n=2}^\infty f_n z^n = \sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{n-1} z^n + \sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{n-2} z^n$.  Then you want to relate each of these to $G(z)$.  For example, $\sum_{n=2}^\infty f_n z^n = G(z) - f_0 - f_1 z$.